# How do I return a complete set of records if any one of them has been updated?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am making a script that gets the incremental updated of data from a DB.

I need some help on getting the whole set of data that is contained in two joined tables whenever one of the records in the seconds table (at least one) has been updated;

So far the only thing that I could come up with is get the Ids from the first table that have been in any way involved in the change and then use those Ids as a filter in a more general query. It works, but it's not pretty and I feel that there might be a better optimised solution to this.

Here's a link to an example:

https://rextester.com/TLCIA97116
(could not get SQL Fiddle to open).

The above example shows two SELECT queries. The second one is my solution and it's result is what I'm looking for. In other words - "give me the records from table A and their related (joined) records from table B, whenever one of the records in table B is added/changed"

The first query is returning the set that has only the updated row, but I need all of them to recalculate some values later and they depend on all records being there.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to handle is using triggers. Add a trigger in the second table, which will push changes/call updates on the first table.

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. I have this query running as a part of an ETL process and it has to be a standalone SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting with a couple of colleagues, it looks like my solution is the one that we have to go with (mostly because of the lack of better ones).

The request is as follows:

```
select * 
from Placements as p 
join PlacementCommissions as pc on p.PlacementId = pc.PlacementId
where p.PlacementId in (select distinct p2.PlacementId from Placements AS p2                  
                  JOIN PlacementCommissions AS pc2 ON p2.PlacementId = pc2.PlacementId
                        where ((pc2.TimeStamp >= @lastSuccessfullETLRun
                        AND pc2.TimeStamp < @startTimeBullhorn)
                           OR (p2.TimeStamp >= @lastSuccessfullETLRun
                           AND p2.TimeStamp < @startTimeBullhorn)))
```